# Security blog - author profiles

Tags: feature-request, blog, design, site-promotion

A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away, we used to have profiles on our security.blogoverflow.com blog.

That is, if you look at any post by me you'll see I have a clickable name which takes you to all posts my me. Fine and dandy, but...! When you click this link, my name becomes gray.

I seem to remember there was  a time we could fill out our wordpress profiles here.

Can we have it back please please please? Did it ever exist, or was it a Jedi mind trick?

An equally acceptable, maybe even preferable alternative in my mind would be to redirect to my network profile. Although I had thought to write a slightly different profile on the blog.

Comment: Suggest asking this on [meta.se]

Comment: I seem to be able to view it just fine, perhaps it's because you are logged in as yourself and it would be redundant?:
http://infosecfrog.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may still be able to, or at least I just now did

1. Log into the blog at https://security.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin
2. Click on 'Profile' on the left hand side
3. Scroll down to the "Biographical info" section
4. Fill our your data
5. Scroll down
6. Click on "Update Profile"

Comment: Yep, but if you go to - http://security.blogoverflow.com/author/scottpack/ for example, you don't get the option to select and see your profile. I've got data filled out, it's just I can't see it anywhere :(